# How to recursively find the sequence in a list with the highest difference?

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

Given this grid:

```py
grid = [[10,23,16,25,12],
        [19,11,8,1,4],
        [3,6,9,7,20],
        [18,24,4,17,5],
        [7,3,4,6,1]]
```

The sequence with the greatest difference between the sum of its odd rows and the sum of its even rows is the sequence of row 1 to row 3. This is because `(10 + 23 + 16 + 25 + 12) - (19 + 11 + 8 + 1 + 4) + (3 + 6 + 9 + 7 + 20) =  88` which is the maximum difference out of all sequences like this.

The sequence should have an even row and an odd row so it must have at least 2 rows. The maximum number of rows depends on the size of the grid.

The problem is I need it to work on an **O(log n) time complexity**. My idea is to use recursion to divide the grid into 2 and solve it from there. However, it doesn't work as I wanted to.

This is my whole code:

```py
import math

class Sequence:
    
    def __init__(self,grids):
        self.grids = grids
        self.calculate_max_difference()
        
    def calculate_max_difference(self):
        # Get the odd and even rows using list slicing
        odd_rows = self.grids[::2]
        even_rows = self.grids[1::2]

        odd_sum = 0
        even_sum = 0
        for odd_lst in odd_rows:
            odd_sum += sum(odd_lst)
        for even_lst in even_rows:
            even_sum += sum(even_lst)

        self.diff = odd_sum - even_sum

def consecutive_seq(start,end,max,grids):
    middle = math.ceil((start+end)/2)
    sequence = []
    for row in range(end-start):
        sequence.append(grids[start+row])
    seq_ins = Sequence(sequence)

    if (end-start) <= 3 and (end-start) > 1:
        return seq_ins.grids
    
    upper_seq = consecutive_seq(start,middle,seq_ins.diff,seq_ins.grids)
    lower_seq = consecutive_seq(middle+1,end,seq_ins.diff,seq_ins.grids)
    greater_seq = upper_seq

    if upper_seq.diff < lower_seq.diff:
        greater_seq = lower_seq
    
    if greater_seq.diff < max:
        return seq_ins.grids

# Sample Input
grid = [[10,23,16,25,12],
        [19,11,8,1,4],
        [3,6,9,7,20],
        [18,24,4,17,5],
        [7,3,4,6,1]]
n = len(grid)

max_seq = consecutive_seq(0,n-1,0,grid)
print(max_seq)
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: So the sequence you are talking about is, for `i`th row, add the its summation to `i+2`th and subtract `i+1`th from the result, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Are you open to using any external module?

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani however it isn't always the case. That example is for a sequence with 3 rows. 4 rows would be (i + (i+2)) - ((i+1) + (i+3)).

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you don't really need a 2d array for this. You can sum up all the rows and only store the sums in a 1D array. So for example

```py
grid = [[10,23,16,25,12],
        [19,11,8,1,4],
        [3,6,9,7,20],
        [18,24,4,17,5],
        [7,3,4,6,1]]
```

turns in to

```py
sums = [sum(row) for row in grid]  # sums = [86, 43, 45, 68, 21]
```

Once you have the sums you have to simply invert the signs for odd indices

```
[86, 43, 45, 68, 21] becomes => [86, -43, 45, -68, 21]
```

Once you have the data in this format, you can use the algorithm for [Finding the largest sum in a contiguous subarray](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/) which has a time complexity of **O(n)**. You might have to make a few small tweaks to that to include at least 2 numbers.

Also if you care only about the difference, you will have to run the algorithm again but this time multiply the even indices by `-1`.

I really don't think you can solve this in **O(log n)** time.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually pretty smart. In regards with the time complexity, do you have any suggestions on how to make it to be O(log n)?

Comment: @NestorDesabille There are only a handful of algorithms that run in `O(log n)` time. So I highly doubt this is possible in `O(log n)` time

Comment: @rickiestRick "I highly doubt this is possible in O(log n) time" << Running an algorithm in O(log n) when n is the size of the input array means *you don't even have enough time to look at the numbers in the array*. There are a few problems where that's possible, for instance searching for a number in a sorted array can be done in O(log n) time, because you can ignore most of the numbers in the array. But as soon as your problem requires looking at all the numbers, it's going to require Ω(n) at minimum.